# maintaining session in elastic Bean

Tags: ubuntu, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

As the number of instances changes from time to time in EBS amazon. If an application is built in PHP how the session will be mantained among several instances? How can we make sure not to delete the Parent instance (The first instance when the app was started)